# How to show multi data Labels on group column highcharts

Tags: css

I have the data that I want to display on column like this:

[image]

I tried [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/SpzBa/19/) but it isn't working. How can I do this?

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -70,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                var allSeries = this.series.chart.series;
                var totalAmount = 0;
                for(var s in allSeries) { totalAmount += allSeries[s].points[this.point.x].Amount; }

                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y + ' (<b>$ ' + this.point.Amount +') <br/>'+
                   'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal + ' (<b>$ ' + totalAmount +')';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                      return this.point.Amount + '%'
                    },

                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [{y: 5, Amount: 100}, {y: 3, Amount: 60}, {y: 4, Amount: 80}]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [{y: 3, Amount: 60}, {y: 4, Amount: 80}, {y: 4, Amount: 80}]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: looks allright to me, try it with google chrome ?

Comment: You should include your code here, not just link it.

Comment: Thanks! I included code, Can give me some suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bzy06gt/5/)**

```
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      useHTML: true,
      color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
      style: {
        textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
      },
      formatter: function() {
        var pointHeight = this.point.shapeArgs.height + 20;
        return '<div class="datalabel" style="position: relative; top: 0px">' + this.point.Amount + '%' + '</div><div class="datalabelInside" style="text-shadow:none;color:#000;position: absolute; top:' + pointHeight / 2  + 'px">' + this.y + '</div>';
      }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Cheralatan! It exactly that i want. But, if i edit data like in https://jsfiddle.net/7bzy06gt/2/ , style of div : class ="datalablelInside", value this.y is not display. Can you give me solution for css that div! thanks!

Comment: Hi Cheralathan, have a small problem, i see that, value of datalabel is override on tooltip, this is bad for me.I tried to fix but its failed. How can fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Hello sinh, I have added positioner properties on the tooltip object. please see the fiddle.

Comment: Very nice,Thanks so much Cheralathan !

Comment: Hi Cheralathan, I have a same problem, I try this code in http://jsfiddle.net/SpzBa/23/  but value of Percent on the top of Columns were wrong, (this value of Percent is value of y in data)
How can i fix that?

Comment: Thanks Cheralathan! Its work!  Can you explain this line code for me? "return this.total+ '%';"

Comment: Highcharts return the percent value on total property. Please try `console.log(this);` before the `return this.total+ '%'`. It makes sense.

Comment: Hi Cheralathan, How are you? ;-)

I have a problem, I try this code in http://jsfiddle.net/sqgq88rd/2/  but shape of value of Percent show on Columns  won't meet exactly my requirement, (this value of Percent is value of y in data). I want like that: 

ex: CPC :  Part 1 has 72.73 % -->> area of Part 1 will be near to 100% more than now!  


 How can i fix that?

Comment: @sinh.vu I couldn't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ Cheralathan, Sorry my problem was difficult to express. I have found solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Cheralathan, Can you give me a solution to fix this my problem that I have post in link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335676/fix-height-of-column-in-stacked-percentage-column-highcharts . Thanks!