# Highcharts : get labels both on column and above

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to have labels both on columns and above, like in this picture:

[image]

Unfortunatly, using `dataLabels`, I only managed to get the labels above:

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled:true,
      formatter: function() { this.point.percentage; }
    }
  }
}
```

Ans I get this result:

[image]

How can I get both labels?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390017/how-to-show-multi-data-labels-on-group-column-highcharts

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I want. I'll try it.

Comment: `stackLabels` will resolve

Comment: You can use dataLabels and stackLabels (you can change format of dataLabels using formatter function). Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/7L1tna44/

Comment: Indeed, the trick was to use both `stackLabels` and `dataLabels`. Thank you very much. If one of you want to post this as an answer so I choose it ... :)