# fix height of column in stacked percentage column highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a stacked percent column chart in this example. http://jsfiddle.net/sqgq88rd/5/. I don't want when I click on legend it the column always becomes 100% so I used stacking : 'stacked' and I want column "Total" always becomes 100%, column "part1" and column "part2" use their percent. I fixed max of yAxis was 100, but height of columns wasn't equal. I try this code .

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 5,
            depth: 100
        },
    },
    title: {
            useHTML: true,
        text: 'Stacked column chart',
        x:-20
    },
    subtitle: {
        useHTML: true,
        text: '',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories : [ 'CPC','QBPC','QTPC','TTHPC','DNPC','QNAPC','QNPC','BDPC','PYPC','KHPC','GLPC','KTPC','DLPC','DNoPC','CGC','NPMU ','CREB ','PEC ','IT','EMEC ','ETC ','PC3I','CC' ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip :  {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}<b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.tyle}</b><br/>Tỷ lệ: <b>({point.y:.0f}%)<b/>'

      },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'stacked'
      },
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          inside: true,
          allowOverlap: true,
          color: '#1C689D',
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          },
          formatter: function() {
            return this.point.tyle
          }
        }
      }

    },
    series: [
    {
          name: 'Total',
          data: [{y:100,tyle:3080},{y:100,tyle:527},{y:100,tyle:743},{y:100,tyle:662},{y:100,tyle:1860},{y:100,tyle:1160},{y:100,tyle:946},{y:100,tyle:944},{y:100,tyle:650},{y:100,tyle:1095},{y:100,tyle:650},{y:100,tyle:474},{y:100,tyle:890},{y:100,tyle:1149},{y:100,tyle:1755},{y:100,tyle:640},{y:100,tyle:689},{y:100,tyle:345},{y:100,tyle:176},{y:100,tyle:133},{y:100,tyle:467},{y:100,tyle:266},{y:100,tyle:108}],
          index:1
      },{
          name: 'Part 1',
          data: [{y:6,tyle:179},{y:3,tyle:17},{y:6,tyle:42},{y:1,tyle:9},{y:1,tyle:12},{y:3,tyle:40},{y:1,tyle:13},{y:2,tyle:17},{y:2,tyle:10},{y:4,tyle:46},{y:7,tyle:45},{y:3,tyle:12},{y:5,tyle:47},{y:4,tyle:41},{y:2,tyle:29},{y:3,tyle:16},{y:0,tyle:3},{y:10,tyle:33},{y:5,tyle:8},{y:3,tyle:4},{y:11,tyle:52},{y:0,tyle:0},{y:0,tyle:0}],
          index:2
      },
      {
          name: 'Part 2',
          data: [{y:2,tyle:50},{y:1,tyle:7},{y:2,tyle:18},{y:0,tyle:3},{y:0,tyle:2},{y:1,tyle:14},{y:0,tyle:2},{y:0,tyle:2},{y:1,tyle:5},{y:2,tyle:25},{y:4,tyle:23},{y:0,tyle:1},{y:3,tyle:23},{y:2,tyle:23},{y:1,tyle:15},{y:2,tyle:12},{y:0,tyle:0},{y:4,tyle:15},{y:1,tyle:1},{y:0,tyle:0},{y:9,tyle:26},{y:0,tyle:0},{y:0,tyle:0}],
          index:2
      }
    ]
});
```

});

How can I fix height of columns is equal and equal 100;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stacking: 'percent'`

Api reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.stacking

Example code:
http://jsfiddle.net/6my8pghf/

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't want  when I click on legend it the column always becomes 100% so I used stacking : 'stacked'.  
I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: You can put your 'total' serie behind your other 2 series using: `plotOptions.column.groupPadding: 0.5`

Comment: Thanks. I think I can fix my problem base on your Example in this link : https://jsfiddle.net/n9p8v2m3/ .

Comment: @ stpoa. Your example is what I want, but I have a small problem, I don't want fix pointWidth, I want to width of columns is dynamic for  others screen ? What way I can do that?

Comment: You can set pointWidth dynamically with Chart.reflow http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.reflow

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are setting your total as 100, and then your other two series as their values, and stacking them all together.

So, your first point, you `100`, plus `6`, plus `2`, for a total of 108.
And so on, for each point, which makes them all different heights.

You need to subtract the values of 'Part 1' and 'Part 2' from your 'Total' series.

Example:

```
$.each(totalData, function(i, point) {
  totalData[i].y = (totalData[i].y - part1Data[i].y - part2Data[i].y);
})
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/sqgq88rd/7/

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I want, when I click on legend it the column "Total" always becomes 100%, column "part1" and column "part2" use their percent. How can I do that?

Comment: Well, I mean, that's what the 100% stacking is for :) I guess I don't understand why this functionality would matter. Generally speaking, this idea of filling in the blank space to 100% just clutters the chart, and makes it more difficult to understand the data. In this chart especially, you can barely see any of the actual data points. I would, first and foremost, recommend better ways to visualize this data.

Comment: That said, to make the `total` series always be 100%, you would have to make 3 data arrays for the total - 100, 100 - part1, and 100 - part2.  Capture the `legendItemClick` event, detect which series are visible, and use the `setData()` method on the `total` series, to update the data with the appropriate array.

Comment: Or, simpler solution: use the full '100' value series; set the y axis max to 100: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/jfj49hpz/

Comment: :) Thanks. I will try to fix base on your solution.